# Big-O Notation of Maclaurin Formula for cos x

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am self-studying the book *Calculus, a Complete Course* By Adams. On the section on Maclaurin formulas for some elementary functions, the formula for $\cos x$ is written as follows with the error in big-O form $$\cos x= 1-\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\frac{x^{4}}{4!}-\cdots+(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}+O(x^{2n+2})$$ I am a beginner, but I managed to figure these out: the odd-order derivatives of the Taylor polynomial are zero because of the term $\sin 0$, so we have just the even-order derivatives (i.e. $\cos 0$). However, I know that the error of the approximation hier (or the Lagrange remainder) is $$E(x)=\frac{\sin s}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$$ and $0<|s|<|x|$. The term $\sin s$, provided that $x<\pi/2$, is nonzero, so why the argument of the big-O is $x^{2n+2}$? instead of $x^{2n+1}$

Comment: $2n+1$ is odd, and you've already argued that the odd order terms of the Taylor polynomial are zero, so ...

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity That's right. But in the error term we have $\sin s$ and this is nonzero. In the terms of the polynomial we have $\sin 0$, which is zero.

Comment: @KavehRad You should also write $+0x+0x^3+...+0x^{2n+1}$. Then the error is in the next higher order, which is $2n+2$.

Comment: But the $2n$'th order expansion and the $2n+1$'th order expansion is the same, so you don't need to consider the error term for the first.

Comment: Is it correct to say that since $0<|s|<|x|$ and $x$ approaches zero (according to the definition of big-O notation), $f^{(2n+1)}$, i.e. sine function $\sin s$ in the remainder term also approaches zero, therefore, we go for $f^{(2n+2)}$ which is a cosine function and nonzero as $x$ approaches zero?